# Read and write data Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am writing a todolist application
there are two screens
MainVC - table
SecondVC - with two testfeeds where the user writes notes

I save when I click on the button

```
private var databaseRef = Database.database().reference()
```

**ActionButton**

```
let user = Auth.auth().currentUser   
self.databaseRef.child((user?.uid)!).child("tasklist").childByAutoId().setValue(["textPrimary":textPrimary,                                                                     "textSecondary":textSecondary])
```

I use childByAutoId() because a user can have many notes
Example my database:

```
GcOialHBMfWxV9AgUJXR4zUsf603 =     { // user.uid
        tasklist =         { // child("tasklist")
            "-N9km0vd6W_gs3ljMRyw" =             { // .childByAutoId()
                textPrimary = 123; //setValue(["textPrimary":textPrimary,
                textSecondary = Tasktask; //  "textSecondary":textSecondary]
            };
            "-N9km4EMruNUvSDsCCAY" =             { // .childByAutoId()
                textPrimary = OtherTask;
                textSecondary = Taskkkkk;
            };
        };
    };
```

How do I get the key of an already created notes?(example **-N9km0vd6W_gs3ljMRyw**)
I load the data like this

```
    // load data in first VC
 let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
    var ref = databaseRef.child("\(user!.uid)").child("tasklist").childByAutoId()
    print(ref)
        ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
             print(snapshot.value)

        })
}
```

.childByAutoId() constantly creates a new key (which is not in the database, and I need a key from the database)
Or do I have the wrong approach? Then what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `snapshot` object in your last code snippet is of type [`DataSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/DataSnapshot). In addition to having a `value`, it also has a `key` - which is the string generated when you call `childByAutoId`.

So:

```
ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
    print(snapshot.key) // 
    print(snapshot.value)
})
```

If you load the entire `tasklist` node, you can loop over the `children` of the snapshot (whose keys you won't know) as shown in the Firebase documentation on [getting a list of nodes by listening for a value event](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events):

```
var tasklistRef = databaseRef.child("\(user!.uid)").child("tasklist")
tasklistRef.observe(.value) { snapshot in
  for taskSnapshot in snapshot.children {
    ...
  }
}
```

To learn more about this, also see:

- [Iterate over snapshot children in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27341888/iterate-over-snapshot-children-in-firebase)
- [How to loop through Firebase data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49354469/how-to-loop-through-firebase-data)
- [Looping in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38023471/looping-in-firebase)

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry if this answer would better a comment, but I wanted to add a code snippet.

From the firebase documentation:

> childByAutoId generates a new child location using a unique key and
> returns a FIRDatabaseReference to it

So as far as I understood, you get the id from the reference (in your example *ref*) and I could imagine it looks like that:

```
// create ref, based on childByAutoId()
var ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("tasks").childByAutoId()

// add value
ref.setValue(task)

// get the id from the reference
let childautoID = ref.key 

// let's see the id in the logs
print(childautoID)
```